# react-native: command not found in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: react-native, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying running react-native from last 2 days but I am not able to run anything ,I followed official page for getting started and followed instructions carefully but everytime terminal gives me this error

npm -v 6.9.0

node -v v12.6.0

java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_212"

these are the versions of requirements i have installed

I copy pasted

- export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
  export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
  export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
  export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
  export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

these inside of .bashrc file in home

can anyone save me please

Comment: You missed in path `$HOME/.npm-global/bin` where react-native placed after `npm i -g react-native-cli` command.

Comment: can you write full statement what i have to include

Comment: export PATH="$HOME/.npm-global/bin:$"/home/chirag/.npm-global/lib"

Comment: i have included this but its still giving me error

Comment: Assuming this method for npm global repo: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally.

Comment: I think this worked i am able to init the project now thanks man you saved me

Comment: now it is giving me new error

Comment: npm ERR! path /home/chirag/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/bd/db/70fef257b7c44d04d790f3733128804a0eb0452b2aff8626bbd2bb31a114
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/chirag/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/bd/db/70fef257b7c44d04d790f3733128804a0eb0452b2aff8626bbd2bb31a114'

Comment: May be you still prepend npm with sudo? Clean cache an reinstall all without sudo.

Comment: yeah i installed ract native cli with sudo but how to clean cache

Comment: sory, not cache - simple uninstall with sudo an install again without sudo.

Comment: it is still giving me same error

Comment: try more simple way: `npx react-native ...`.

Comment: i typed npx react-native init project still it got the same error

Comment: can you fully reinstall nodejs? (from now without superuser). Or remove manualy   folder `/home/chirag/.npm/` - there are plenty files with superuser rights.

Comment: i have deleted everything should i install node using this command sudo apt install nodejs or apt install nodejs

Comment: sudo only for `apt install nodejs` - all `npm i -g` without sudo.

Comment: i reinstalled node and npm and ran npm install -g react-native-cli without sudo but it is not installing giving error ===checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

Comment: again manually change npm’s default directory https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: yes finally i am able to make react projects thank you so so muchhhhhh

Comment: Congratulations. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

React Native site has good [installation guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) for React Native CLI on Linux, but sometimes command `npm install -g react-native-cli` fails with error

> checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules

because only `root` can access directory where NPM install global packages. You might want to run `sudo npm install -g react-native-cli` but you shouldn`t. 
(If you did it, run please:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm`

to eliminate consequences).
The most preferred solution will be [changing npm’s default directory](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally):

- create a directory for global installations:

  mkdir ~/.npm-global
- Configure npm to use the new directory path:

  npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
- Open ~/.bashrc (or ~/.profile) file and add this line:

  export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
- On the command line, update your system variables:

  source ~/.bashrc

Now you can install `react-native-cli` globally without using sudo:
`npm install -g react-native-cli`.
After that `react-native init` should work.